# How to choose quarkus profile when running app under Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, quarkus

When running my app from within Idea, I see command line ends with

```
... -Ddebug=38605 quarkus:dev
```

and `dev` profile is active. It doesn't depend on whether I press `debug` button or `run` button.

How to switch to `prod` profile? If I go to run configuration and enter

[image]

the command line changes to

```
... -Ddebug=38605 quarkus:dev -P prod
```

and the profile remains `dev`

Answer (score 19):

This is not a Maven profile but a Quarkus profile.

You need to use `-Dquarkus.profile=prod` or the `QUARKUS_PROFILE` environment variable.

See https://quarkus.io/guides/config#configuration-profiles for more details.

Comment: But why the original command line is `... quarkus:dev ` but not `... -Dquarkus.profile=dev`?

Comment: Because `quarkus:dev` is more than a configuration profile. It's a whole other Maven mojo.

Comment: So, can I change this from `IDE`?

Comment: changing quarkus profile at runtime doesn't seem to work with Quarkus version 2.x

Answer (score 10):

You should use Runner - VM Options = `-Dquarkus.profile=prod` to specify quarkus profile in IntelliJ IDEA Run Configuration.

[image: Quarkus Profile set in VM Options]

There is an issue in IntelliJ IDEA tracker, probably it should be simpler: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259900